# Building from SRPMs on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, rpmbuild

I'm trying to compile [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) on CentOS 6.5 using `rpmbuild`. I found SRPMs for Fedora Core and am trying to rebuild them on my CentOS install but am running into dependency issues.

Basically, while I've installed newer versions of packages, `rpmbuild` doesn't seem to detect them. Here is an example:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild xcb-util-image-0.3.9-2.fc19.src.rpm 

Installing xcb-util-image-0.3.9-2.fc19.src.rpm
warning: InstallSourcePackage at: psm.c:244: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fb4b18e6: NOKEY
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
error: Failed build dependencies:
    pkgconfig(xcb-util) >= 0.3.8 is needed by xcb-util-image-0.3.9-2.el6.x86_64
```

But as you can see here, I clearly have `xcb-util` > 0.3.8 installed:

```
$ sudo yum list installed | grep xcb-util                  
xcb-util.x86_64                        0.3.6-1.el6               @UIedited_0/6.5
xcb-util.x86_64                        0.3.9-2.el6               installed
```

I tried removing the older version of `xcb-util` but there are too many packages that depend on that.

Similar issue with building awesome when it comes to `cmake`:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild awesome-3.5.1-2.fc18.src.rpm
Installing awesome-3.5.1-2.fc18.src.rpm
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
error: Failed build dependencies:
    cmake >= 2.8.0 is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    lua-ldoc is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(libev) is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(xcb-util) >= 0.3.8 is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(xcb-keysyms) >= 0.3.4 is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(xcb-icccm) >= 0.3.8 is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(xcb-image) >= 0.3.0 is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(cairo-xcb) is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(libstartup-notification-1.0) >= 0.10 is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(libxdg-basedir) >= 1.0.0 is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
    lua-lgi is needed by awesome-3.5.1-2.el6.x86_64
$ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.11.2
$ sudo yum list installed | grep cmake
cmake28.x86_64                         2.8.11.2-1.el6            @dell-epel
```

So any `yum`/`rpm` gurus out there who can point me in the right direction? I'd rather not have to build everything from source, so I was hoping to get `rpmbuild` working with the SRPMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this, I was not able to get this working and didn't want to go down the path of compiling all the dependencies from source, so I ended up abandoning this endeavor in favor of getting my build working on Fedora 20 and installing Awesome from official repos.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your systems has multiple versions of some packages installed. If you have the "yum-utils" package installed, try the following command to remove the older versions of those packages and then see whether the rpmbuild works:

```
sudo /usr/bin/package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

Comment: So if I run that command, yum wants to remove about 75 additional packages such as gdm, Thunar, gnome-desktop, etc. which depend on it. I'd like to have them just use the newer version but I'm not sure if that is possible.